# Do any schools offer teaching or research assistantships via distance education?

Tags: research-assistantship, teaching-assistant, distance-learning, online-degree

I would like to complete an MRes or PhD, but do not live in an area with any schools. I would rather not relocate. I see that many schools offer paid MRes or PhD programs entirely via distance. Do schools sometimes also offer teaching or research assistantships via distance as well?

Comment: I am not aware of a single credible online/distance PhD program.

Comment: How would that work? You'd teach via video link? Seems unlikely...

Comment: The University of Birmingham has many PhDs and other research degrees via distance. Many schools, including Harvard, Yale, Columbia, etc. offer Web-based courses. Why is it so unlikely?

Comment: @Village online courses are not at all similar to online advising

Answer (score 1):

Graduate study is learning to do research, by working with your advisor and a research group, mostly hand in hand. A small part of that you'll be able to do remotely, but a minority in any case.

Perhaps you can find a job as a TA for some of the online courses, but if I was to select somebody to assist me in this, I'd select somebody I know personally (and even have at hand for coordination or to pull their ears if something goes awry).